# Dynamic table names with same structure in C# and EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

how can I create dynamic table names with the same columns but different table names in C# and EF Core?
For example:
we would like to create tables for collecting emails with the same table structure just different names so each customer has its own table for storing emails. Tables would be generated when the user registers for our service.

EmailTable_{UserGuid}

The reason for this is that each customer can have a collection of 1million+ emails and it would be easier for us to store emails for each customer in its own table for later data analysis, reports, etc.

Comment: Are you saying your backend cannot hold millions * customers rows? Your backend might also have capabilities like inheritance, partitioning, sharding.

Comment: I'd say it sounds like a poor design decision. You can use row level scurity to separate the user rows securely instead. It's not a problem with millions (or perhaps billions?) of rows and partitioning would be a good idea as well in the long run if space is an issue. Also since it's probably/hopefully immutable rows maybe other storage solutions would be a better idea

Comment: I didn't remember to use partitioning. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you're not there yet.  Give each customer an entire database instead.  Then at runtime point the DbContext to the customer-specific database.

What you are proposing will work, sort-of.  You would need a separate DbContext subtype for each customer, as OnModelCreating only runs once per DbContext subtype.

Comment: would prefer to have one Db and just multiple tables for emails. On the old app, we have 7K users and don't want to create that many DBs